# cmake 3.11 installation in solaris11

Tags: cmake, installation, solaris

I am new to solaris 11 machine. I have a vitual box and I can only interact via command promt. I am trying to install cmake 3.11 version. I tried downloading cmake source code and building it. But failed at one point where in code uses c++11 and the our gcc compiler is not able to compile it.

It will be very greatfull if anyone can give me steps for installing and using cmake in solaris11.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The better way is to use existing one from here https://www.opencsw.org/package/cmake/ unless you explicitly requires exactly v3.11. In this case I would recommend you upgrade your compiler.

Comment: opencsw.org/package/cmake contains 3.4 version of cmake. I am using cmake to build zookeeper native c client on solaris machine and the CmakeList.txt file of zookeeper 3.4.12 has restriction on cmake version to be more than 3.6.

Comment: Then you have some options. First - edit ZooKeeper CMakeLists.txt and change it to 3.4 (I'm pretty sure that it should work on 3.4 as well). Second - start hacking clang or gcc on Solaris to make them supporting c++11 (really hard way). Third - start hacking CMake to reduce it dependency from c++11 (AFAIR it only required for cmake-server mode so you can just disable this functionality).

Comment: @AshwiniJ, you may want to consider updating cmake for OpenCSW community

Answer (score 1):

Solaris 11 offers a cmake package in its package repos, so `pkg install cmake` as root should do it.

Comment: Solaris 11 repo contains cmake 2.8.6 version. If we do "pkg install cmake", it will install 2.8.6 version. But we need the cmake to be of latest version. :(